# Create a image file from binary data in Ruby

Tags: ruby, image, binary-data

I am able to access the binary data of a file and store it in a varible like this

```
s = File.binread("sample_22122015_03.jpg")
bits = s.unpack("B*")[0]
```

where bits has data like this "101001001010100100......."

However, I want to do some changes and again write the binary data back to a new image, but I am unable to.

I am using

```
File.open('shipping_label_new.jpg', 'wb') do|f|
f.write(Base64.decode64(bits))
end
```

but it's not working and I see that the image is corrupt.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
s = File.binread("test_img.jpg")
bits = s.unpack("B*")

File.open('new_test_img.jpg', 'wb') do|f|
  f.write(bits.pack("B*"))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The reverse of `String.unpack` is `Array.pack`:

```
 :007 > bits = 'abc'.unpack("B*")
 => ["011000010110001001100011"]
 :008 > bits.pack("B*")
 => "abc"
```

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for your reply. so how can i create image of binary data?

Comment: The rest of your code was correct, you open the file in 'wb' mode and write the data to it.  The data will be in the form of a string.

Comment: Hello Keith, so i cannot create the file directly from 0 and 1, am i correct? we need to pack it again?

Comment: That's correct.  It makes sense. doesn't it?  You may change the data, but need to restore it to the original format when you save it.  It must be in the format specified by the image specification.  0's and 1's as bytes will be very different.

Comment: Good point, Keith. @opensource-ios, by saying that you are willing to change the data within the string of "bits" you are extracting from a JPEG image, I assume you rather intimately familiar with how the JPEG file format is constructed. Changing the data of a JPEG at the bit level is a very specialized task that requires mapping a nested series of structures to that bit-wise data and tweaking the data perfectly. So, when you say, "i see that the image is corrupt," (even if you saved the data correctly) are you sure you've changed the correct data?

Comment: @WilliamDaniel The OP has used unpack to unserialize the data but decode64 to reserialize it.  Even if the data were untouched, the reserialized data would be different from the original data.  Excellent point about the delicacy of modifying this binary data, I was wondering about that too.